# Delete lines until a header with sed

Tags: sed, windows

I am incorporating SED into a Windows batch file.  I've got it working for deleting the first seven lines of a text file:

```
SED "1,7d"
```

However, I'd like to make it a smarter statement.  Essentially, I have a huge text file that I want to lop off the first few lines…and keep everything from the column heading and below.  The first line of text I want is line 8 and is "Year" with quotes.

I've tried the following and I'm receiving an error in the command window (running the batch file):

```
SED "1,/"Year"/!d"
```

I am putting in the input and output files after the expression.

Comment: Do you have an `awk` to use? `awk '/Year/{found=1}found'`. And what do you mean "output files after the expression"? sed only takes input files on the command line

Comment: “I'm receiving an error”: so what's the error? And why are you asking about a Windows script on a Unix site? I suggest reposting on [su], with the error message.

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk.  What I meant by output files is that after this code I have the target.txt > output.txt

Comment: The error is:

SED: -e expression #1, char 11: Unknown command: "\"

Since the SED executable I'm using is based on UNIX processes, I felt I may get a better response from a UNIX-focused site.  I may try the other one suggested.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because your problem appears to be at least partly with quoting issues with Microsoft's cmd.exe shell. SuperUser would be a better site for this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because your problem appears to be at least partly with quoting issues with Microsoft's cmd.exe shell. SuperUser would be a better site for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the quoting behaviour on windows,
but you could try this:

```
SED '1,/"Year"/!d'
```

Comment: This also did not work, with a different error message:

SED: -e expression #1, char 1: Unknown command "''"

Comment: I think you really need to install CYGWIN, and use the sed that comes with it.  That error message makes no sense to me as it indicates that your sed thinks of a single quote as a command.

Comment: Yeah, that's how quoting on Windows works.  Since this is a Unix site, it might be best to simply close the question as off-topic ...?

Comment: As far as I know, `cmd` doesn't give a dime on quoting. (For example `echo "Hello"` outputs `"Hello"`, including the quotes.) So I would try simply `sed 1,/"Year"/!d`, without outer quotes.

Answer (score 0):

[This wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Quotation_marks_and_spaces_in_passed_strings) indicates inner quotes should be tripled:

```
SED "1,/"""Year"""/!d"
```

untested.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.